# How to invalidate cached property?

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, bltoolkit

In my ASP.NET web site I persist objects retrieved from DB for some time and make sure that the only single instance of object is created per DB record.

I also use [InstanceCache] to cache calculated value for one of business objects, object is kept in cache for the duration of user session.

Today, though, I came across the use-case when I would like to invalidate cached value.

How can I do this for properties that are cached using [InstanceCache]?

Please advise.

Thank you.

Comment: did you try the `ClearCache` methods as I suggested? Did they work for you? Some feedback would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I think you may be able to do that by using one of the `ClearCache` static methods of the [`CacheAspect`](https://github.com/igor-tkachev/bltoolkit/blob/9912c141f13f4de2f69fd3de0d07106d722d9b69/Source/Aspects/CacheAspect.cs) class, that allow clearing the cache at different levels of granularity:

```
public static void ClearCache(MethodInfo methodInfo);
public static void ClearCache(Type declaringType, string methodName, params Type[] types);
public static void ClearCache(Type declaringType, string methodName, Type[] types, object[] values);
public static void ClearCache(Type declaringType);
public static void ClearCache();
```

If you want to clear the cache only for the specific `[InstanceCache]` property, you will need to get its `MethodInfo` (for the "get" method of the property I think) using reflection and pass that along to the first variant.

This seems to work for regular `[Cache]` attribute annotations, so if clearing the cache for `[InstanceCache]` items is at all supported, this would be the route to go.

Comment: So far I decided to delete the instance itself... which in turn causes new cache value to be calculated, so I don't need to invalidate cache NOW. But idea to call static method ClearCache looks... too complex. Will give it a try to better understand it anyway.
Thanks!